# Can I ask questions about rock cutting and gem cutting here?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can I ask questions on this SE regarding things such as gem tumbling, cabbing, and faceting here along with concepts such as gem "fire"? I'm guessing not, at least to the first, because that's more of an artistic concept rather than a science based concept. But other people's thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read any books by Antoinette L. Matlins?  Also June Culp Zeitner?    I would check your local library for Zeitner first (I think you would really like her books) if they don't have them maybe they could get it for you through inter-library loan. I am interested in this area too, but not so much the faceting because I'm getting too old to fool with something that is complicated. :).

Comment: There is also "Rock and Gem" magazine which you probably know already.

Comment: Also you might want to look into classes like this one day. I have never attended. There are probably other classes like this around the country too. http://www.lapidaryschool.org/

Comment: I expect there are sites with more knowledge in the area than this one.

Comment: @haresfur but on the SE network?

Answer (score 4):

I think questions on rock cutting and gem cutting for artistic or industrial purposes is off topic for Earth Science stack exchange.  Some aspects may be on-topic, such as scientific aspects of rock formation and how this affects hardness and other properties relevant for artists.  But there is currently no Stack Exchange site where the artistic or industrial aspects are on-topic.

Potentially, you could propose to broaden the scope of the proposed [Metal working](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113930/metal-workers) site to include working on rocks and gems.  Unfortunately, that proposal appears to move rather slowly so it doesn't appear too likely it's going ahead (with or without broadened scope).